# Why isn't absolute path for url() function working?

Tags: css

I'm trying to display an image on the background of a site through CSS. I want the image to be kept in a separate folder than the CSS/HTML file. The image only displays, if I place it in the same folder as the CSS/HTML file, and reference its name only.

The code is in `C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\templates` and the image is in `C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\pictures`. If I try using the absolute path it won't display. It will only display if I place the picture in the templates folder.

```
<!--This code works if I place the picture in the template file-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("picture.png");
}
</style>
</head>
</html>

<!--This code doesn't work-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\pictures\picture.png");
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add the file:/// prefix before the url according to the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519388/can-i-use-an-image-from-my-local-file-system-as-background-in-html

Comment: can you please share the error showing in the console?

Comment: Also try relative path url("../pictures/picture.png") and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks @YochaiAkoka, the file:/// prefix worked for absolute references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css

```
Body{

background-image: url("../pictures/picture.png")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your folder structure, you might need to do a *../pictures/picture.png*

```
background-image: url("../pcitures/picture.png");
```

To find the image when it's in the pictures folder.  The first **'.'** means the current directory(.css file), while the second **'../'**  means the parent directory (projects folder). From there, you navigate to pictures folder and then directly link with the picture image. Use this link to learn about file paths. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

**Avoid absolute file path**. Imagine transferring your files to a new server, you'll have to rewrite the file path again.

```
 background-image: url("C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\pictures\picture.png");
```